# Adding options to select field using javascript from a json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
      var json = $.getJSON("../category.json", function() {
            alert(2);
        })
         .done(function() {
            console.log( "second success" );    
            var var1 = document.getElementsByClassName('category');
            var1.innerHTML = "<option value='" + key + "'>" + val + "</option>";
            alert(var1);
         })
        .fail(function() {
          alert( "error" );
          });
```

I want to values from json file as options to my select field. But my code always shows alert error. Please tell me what is wrong with it ?

Comment: change the fail handler to `function (jqXhr, status, error) {
        alert(status + ':' + error + ':' + jqXhr.responseText)
    }
`

Comment: make sure your JSON is valid

Comment: [{"NAME":"chair","0":"chair"},{"NAME":"bed","0":"bed"},{"NAME":"table","0":"table"},{"NAME":"almira","0":"almira"}]                                                                                 this is my json file.

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting your `key` and `value` parameters. In fact it doesn't look like you're getting your JSON results at all.

Change your done method to

```
.done(function( data ) { /* do stuff */ }
```

Now your JSON results will be stored in data.
Then you may need to loop through the results. See the example **[here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)**

Comment: I changed the function to following still it does not work.                                                                    var json= $.getJSON("../category.json", function(data) {alert(data);
       });

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var json = $.getJSON("../category.json", function(data) {
    alert(2);
})
.done(function(data) {
    console.log( "second success" );    
    var var1 = document.getElementsByClassName('category');
       $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
         var1.innerHTML += "<option value='" + key + "'>" + val + "</option>";
         alert(var1);
     });
       alert(var1);
    })
.fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not valid: You cannot use a number as a JSON key

```
[
    {
        "NAME":"chair",
        "0":"chair"                     <-- error
    },
    {
        "NAME":"bed",
        "0":"bed"                       <-- error
    },
    {
        "NAME":"table",
        "0":"tabl‌​e"                     <-- error
    },
    {
        "NAME":"almira",
        "0":"almira"                    <-- error
    }
]
```

Try running your JSON through an online JSON parser and the error will come up.
Alternatively, change your error handler to include more information

```
.fail(function (jqXhr, status, error) { 
    alert(status + ':' + error + ':' + jqXhr.responseText) }
});
```